# How to prevent the mixed content issue in Keycloak deployed to Okteto?

Tags: keycloak

I deployed my Keycloak instance to Okteto, https://keycloak-jeff-tian.cloud.okteto.net/. The docker file I used is as follows (https://github.com/Jeff-Tian/keycloak-heroku/blob/4647517ad76ba9ac28283dc24c7f291d25f4d84e/Dockerfile.test):

```
FROM quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:latest

COPY idps/wechat-mobile/keycloak-services-social-weixin.jar \
    /opt/keycloak/providers/
COPY idps/wechat-mobile/templates/realm-identity-provider-weixin-ext.html \
    /opt/keycloak/themes/base/admin/resources/partials
COPY idps/wechat-mobile/templates/realm-identity-provider-weixin.html \
    /opt/keycloak/themes/base/admin/resources/partials

COPY idps/wecom/keycloak-services-social-wechat-work.jar \
    /opt/keycloak/providers/
COPY idps/wecom/templates/realm-identity-provider-wechat-work.html \
    /opt/keycloak/themes/base/admin/resources/partials
COPY idps/wecom/templates/realm-identity-provider-wechat-work-ext.html \
    /opt/keycloak/themes/base/admin/resources/partials


#COPY  temp/* /opt/keycloak/themes/base/admin/resources/partials
#COPY  ui/font_iconfont /opt/keycloak/themes/keycloak/common/resources/lib/font_iconfont
#COPY  ui/theme.properties /opt/keycloak/themes/keycloak/login/
COPY  target/keycloak-justauth-12.0.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar /opt/keycloak/providers/

COPY  target/keycloak-justauth-12.0.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar /opt/keycloak/deployments/

ENV KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT=false
ENV KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT_HTTPS=false
ENV KC_HTTP_ENABLED=true
ENV PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING=true
ENV FRONTEND_URL=https://keycloak-jeff-tian.cloud.okteto.net
ENV KC_HOSTNAME_URL=https://keycloak-jeff-tian.cloud.okteto.net

CMD ["start", "--proxy=passthrough", "--db=postgres", "--db-url=$DB_URL", "--db-username=$DB_USERNAME", "--db-password=$DB_PASSWORD", "--features=\"preview,scripts\""]
```

After I logged in to the admin console, the page can't be loaded due to mixed content:
[image]

[image]

I am expecting that the request urls should start with "https://" instead of "http://". How do I force them be https?

Comment: In your Keycloak, what is the frontend url configured as in Realm Settings-> General tab? I'm assuming you are using the latest version of Keycloak..

Comment: In my configuration, I have PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING=true and REDIRECT_SOCKET=proxy-https

Answer (score 0):

Set env variable `KC_HOSTNAME_ADMIN_URL` to your desired URL also.

```
ENV KC_HOSTNAME_ADMIN_URL=https://keycloak-jeff-tian.cloud.okteto.net
```

Also, remove the FRONTEND_URL; this should be inferred properly.